# Compass throwing in forward slash in front of images when making sprites

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sprite

I am using Compass to create sprites. The sprites are being created but the css output is pointing to the wrong place for the images directory.

the output is:

```
.menu-sprite, .menu-about, .menu-art, .menu-drum, .menu-links, 
.menu-music, .menu-science, .menu-writing {
    background: url('/images/menu-sb7e36b009c.png') no-repeat;
}
```

but i want it to be:

```
.menu-sprite, .menu-about, .menu-art, .menu-drum, .menu-links, 
.menu-music, .menu-science, .menu-writing {
    background: url('images/menu-sb7e36b009c.png') no-repeat;
}
```

here is my confib.rb setup:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "."
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

and here is how im calling the sprites in my scss file:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites/base";
@import "menu/*.png";
@include all-menu-sprites;
```

what am i doing wrong? How can i remove that first slash in front of images?

thanks for any help.

Comment: I found the answer. just needed to add

`relative_assets = true`

to the confib.rb

Answer (score 6):

By default, compass uses absolute paths for all assets.

To change this behaviour, add this line to your config.rb:

```
relative_assets = true
```

Otherwise, you could also change the 'http_path' option to point to where your project sites on your deployment server.