# sprite-url() returns incorrect path

Tags: sass, gruntjs, gulp, compass, grunt-contrib-compass

I am using compass with gulp.
I am generating sprites and have the following mixin:

```
$sprite-icons: sprite-map("sprite-icons/*.png");
$sprite-icons-url: sprite-url($sprite-icons);

@mixin sprite-icon($name) {
    background-image: $sprite-icons-url;
    background-position: sprite-position($sprite-icons, $name);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The gulp task I have takes `app/styles/index.scss` and compile it into `build/styles/index.css`. The images are takes from `app/assets/images/sprite-icons` and I want the sprite image to be in `build/assets/images`.

I am running compass with the following arguments:

```
images_dir = 'app/assets/images'
css_dir = 'build/styles'
sass_dir = 'app/styles'
generated_images_path = 'build/assets/images'
```

Now I have the following style in one of my scss files:

```
.my-image {
    @include sprite-icon('pin-small');
}
```

And I got:

```
.my-image {
  background-image: url('../../assets/images/sprite-icons-sc86bb5a991.png');
  background-position: 0 -669px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The thing is that I need the background image to be:

```
background-image: url('/assets/images/sprite-icons-sc86bb5a991.png');
```

This is happened also when using grunt (the framework doesn't really matters).

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am not certain how you would expect `assets/images/sprite-icons-sc86bb5a991.png` to work.  You've specified that your CSS files get compiled to `build/styles`, but your images are getting generated in `build/assets/images`.  Unless you're moving your CSS files after the fact, the path would have to be `../assets/images/sprite-icons-sc86bb5a991.png` in order to work.

Comment: You right. But I am looking for a way that the assets will be absolute path: url('/assets/images/sprite-icons-sc86bb5a991.png');

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228243/compass-adding-leading-slash-when-generating-sprite

Comment: @cimmanon This is related but not the solution. Relative assets does nothing in my case (I want the path to be absolute). The related question is the opposite question.

Comment: Right.  The problem is that you have enabled relative_assets, so do the opposite...  Most people *want* relative assets and the default behavior is to *not* have relative assets.

Comment: @cimmanon It doesn't work...