# Influence image-url for SASS / SCSS / Compass in Visual Studio & Web Essentials

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sass, compass-sass, web-essentials

I have scss file in Visual Studio, I've imported compass this guide:

[SASS AND SCSS IN VISUAL STUDIO 2013 WITH WEB ESSENTIALS – STARRING COMPASS AND SUSY](https://pwkad.wordpress.com/2014/05/30/using-scss-in-visual-studio-2013-with-web-essentials-starring-compass-and-susy/)

However now when I do in scss:

```
background: image-url('../img32/intro.jpg');
```

I get:

```
background: url("/../img32/intro.jpg")
```

How can I influence that output path? Can I somehow say to SASS compiler not to change path at all (just leave ../img/intro.jpg)?

EDIT: **I don't have access to config.rb, linked answer is not applicable to my situation.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compass adding leading slash when generating sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228243/compass-adding-leading-slash-when-generating-sprite)

Comment: @cimmanon I don't have access to config.rb, that answer is not applicable to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you you can't do the solution above maybe creating a mixin to handle your background image will be the best solution for. So I'm thinking something like this.

First create a generic image path variable like so...

```
$base-image-path: "../img32/";
```

Then add the mixin that will handle compiling out the background image like so...

```
@mixin background-image($file, $type) {
    background-image: url($base-image-path + $file + '.' + $type);
}
```

Finally where ever you need a background image call the mixin like so...

```
@include background-image(sample-bg, png);
```

Hopefully this will bypass the issue you're having until they create a permit fix for it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants to know how to configure the generated path, not go through their entire project and rewrite every single instance where they're using this function.  Also, you're overwriting the background-image mixin provided by Compass.